# C# to VB.net - syntax issue with 2 dimmension array

Tags: .net, servicestack, c#-to-vb.net

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the below code, I am getting `Value of type '2-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)'`

VB.net code:

```
MyBase.SetConfig(New EndpointHostConfig() With {
              .GlobalResponseHeaders = {
             {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"},
             {"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"},
             {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"}
              }
            })
```

And here is C# code I used as a starter point:

```
base.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
    {
        GlobalResponseHeaders = {
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
        },
    });
```

Any suggestions much appreciated

---

The below works OK:

```
Dim CorsHeaders As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            CorsHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            CorsHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
            CorsHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

            MyBase.SetConfig(New EndpointHostConfig() With {
               .GlobalResponseHeaders = CorsHeaders
            })
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the Dictionary constructor with the From keyword:

```
MyBase.SetConfig(New EndpointHostConfig() With {
   .GlobalResponseHeaders = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
      {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"},
      {"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"},
      {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"}
   }
})
```

See [Collection Initializers (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a dictionary like:

```
GlobalResponseHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
          {
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" }
          }
```

See: [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx)

Comment: This works: `Dim CorsHeaders As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
   CorsHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
   CorsHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
   CorsHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

   MyBase.SetConfig(New EndpointHostConfig() With {
      .GlobalResponseHeaders = CorsHeaders
   })`